# How to set (or at least read) the input sampling rate of a Realtek HD Audio card?

Tags: audio

The official driver allows a lot of settings, but I could not find any settings or any info about the sampling rate of the input.

I guess it's 44.1 KHz, I assume this information from the quality of the recording I can make with it.

Is there a way to check this for sure?

Comment: This should be possible to set within the DAW itself (depending on what you use). Since you're using a standard sound card, 44.1Khz is probably more than sufficient for your needs.

Comment: @DaveRook : it's not sufficient, as I'm not recording real sound, but other kind of data for later analysis. I need approximately the double sampling rate, so I either need to change it, or get confirmation about whether it is truly impossible to have more than 44.1 KHz (in this case I have to buy another one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually depends on the Realtek HD audio chip used in your audio card. For laptops it is usually 16bit/48KHz maximum, but for chips used in the MoBos it is usually 16bit/192KHz maximum

With some good audio cards like Creative, Asus etc. you can get 24bit/192KHZ recording quality

You can easily check the properties of the recorded audio after you test record something

[image] [image]